# simple geocoding example

Tags: android, geocoding

I'm implementing a simple Geo-coding example where user enters an address and gets its latitude and longitude.

```
                addr = Area_edtxt.getText().toString();
                try {
                    list_addr = gc.getFromLocationName(addr, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("Location lookup failed", e.getMessage());
                }
                if (list_addr != null && list_addr.size() > 0 ){
                     latitude = list_addr.get(0).getLatitude();
                     longitude = list_addr.get(0).getLongitude();
                     latitude_edtxt.setText(latitude.toString());
                     longitude_edtxt.setText(longitude.toString());
                }else {
                    latitude_edtxt.setText("Address not found");
                }
```

but shows me error : Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt' : Permission denied.

Comment: Its a crash. I think there is a Excpetion somewhere in your log.

Comment: it shows uncaught exception warning and nullpointer exception error

Comment: Are you running your application in the emulator? Or do you have a custom ROM installed?

Comment: OK do you have specified a sdcard? because /data/anr/Traces.txt gets written on the sdcard if some operation on the gui thread takes to long. ANR stands for Application Not Responding.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Comment: not yet....but let me tell u 1 that Reverse Geocoding works very well in same Emulator.

Comment: Maybe because the operation is shorter to complete. I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick try you could use an AsyncTask 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class GeocodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List> {
 protected Long doInBackground(String... address) {
  try {
         return gc.getFromLocationName(address[0], 1)
      } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("Location lookup failed", e.getMessage());
    }
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
     if (list_addr != null && list_addr.size() > 0 ){
         latitude = list_addr.get(0).getLatitude();
         longitude = list_addr.get(0).getLongitude();
         latitude_edtxt.setText(latitude.toString());
         longitude_edtxt.setText(longitude.toString());
     }else {
         latitude_edtxt.setText("Address not found");
     }
 }
```

}

```
new GeocodeTask().execute(addr);
```

Comment: i have error:forward Geocode : no feature in Glocation. same error whatever address i enter.